# Will new civilians spawn mid-mission? (Or: I'm out of cable ties, can I just kill everyone?)

Tags: payday-2

I was soloing Jewelry Store on Normal the other day to farm cards.  When you have two or more players, jewelry store can be completed in less than 60 seconds: one person drops ECM and gets one bag, the other person tosses two bags.

Well, I didn't have that option. So I had to run in, van the first bag, drop ECM, van the second bag, scream at everyone, and try to make it back to the van before the cell phones came out and the coward escape driver bailed.  It can be done, but it's hard.

So then I thought "*What if I just kill everyone?*". No matter how thoroughly I checked the area for survivors, though, someone always called the cops midway through my heist.

**Does Payday spawn extra civilians mid-mission if enough of them are killed, or is the number of civilians (living or dead) fixed throughout?**

Comment: Murder everything that isn't tied down. Not only does it increase your chances of success but it's also an imaginary message for all of those that got to live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, on some mission.  For example, it is scripted for civs to spawn during the GO Bank mission, as that is part of the challenge when trying to stealth it, trying to keep civillians down.

Comment: Yes, GO Bank is an exception. The moment the time lock is started, even more civs will spawn and also enter the bank.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen any mission where it was the case.  Typically in the bank and diamond store heists, we kill all the civilians in the streets plus those we cannot cable tie.  It greatly reduces the chances to trigger the alarm.

That being, some of the civilians have specific spanwing cycles: in the bank heist for instance, those on the streets can get out of reach for a certain time (getting out of the area by one of the three street ends, and getting back later by another one), so watch out.

Comment: That's gotta be what happened!  The ones I missed must have been off-map.

Comment: Yep, this last civilian is becoming a more and more well known pitfall in the bank heist: gotta keep an eye on him while robbing the safe ;)